# What is the meaning of "draining the swamp"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

What is the meaning of "draining the swamp" in this article?

> “Speaking of **draining the swamp**, Donna Brazile did it again,” Mr. Trump said. “WikiLeaks today, she gave the questions to a debate to Hillary Clinton. And that was from a couple of weeks ago. Happened again, but this time far worse. She gave the questions to a debate to Hillary Clinton.”

It's from Washington news: [Donna Brazile fired as CNN contributor after tipping off Clinton to debate questions](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/oct/31/donna-brazile-fired-cnn-contributor/)

Answer (score 5):

"***[Drain the swamp](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drain%20the%20swamp)***":

> - originally means to get rid of the malaria-carrying mosquitoes by draining the swamp. Figuratively, "drain the swamp" means "to exterminate something that is harmful" or anything that most of the people hate such as corruption or government waste. This term is especially attractive for campaigning politicians.

(U.D.)

"Drain The Swamp" is in keeping with Trump's blunt manner of speaking. He is promising  to clean out perceived corruption in D.C.

“[Drain the swamp](http://www.redstate.com/diary/barrypopik/2010/07/29/origin-and-history-of-drain-the-swamp-mother-jones-reagan-rumsfeld-pelosi/)” has had a long history in American politics:

> - In the 1900s and 1910s, Mother Jones and others said that we should “drain the swamp” that breeds capitalists. Others have written that we should “drain the swamp” that breeds socialists.
> - Ronald Reagan reminded all, in 1983 after a year in office, that he came to Washington to “drain the swamp” of big government. After 9-11, Donald Rumsfeld said that we should “drain the swamp” where terrorism breeds.

(www.redstate.com)